# MSSQL with Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm running Python 2.7 with Django/DRF installed on Win 10 Enterprise. My goal is to access a legacy MSSQL database that's running now on SQL Server 2017 on this machine.

I've had some trouble on a couple of different tries getting Python to work with MSSQL at all, usually in some obscure error. I've gotten Django to work fine with MySQL, Postgres, and SQLite otherwise. However, this is a database that I designed many years ago when I was using .NET/MSSQL professionally, and the database is currently being used in production, and some of the clients are actually using legacy MS Access as an ADO project (cringe) to access MSSQL, so moving everything over to a different RDBMS this late in the game is not very feasible. It will create a lot more trouble than it's worth.

On a side note I did some preliminary testing with .NET Core as a test for possibly using it as just a Web API server to access the DB, I was not happy with some of the movements that were done in the EF Core arena. It was very slow in my tests, and didn't support some things that I need. I wrote my own ORM for .NET Framework a while back, but it would take work to port it to .NET Core. The inspectdb command with Django was what I was hoping for as it takes all that manual model work out of the equation and I have many tables and views in this database. I don't know of any equivalent in the .NET Core world.

I've followed the instructions here https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation to install django-mssql via pip and configure my DB, but when I run inspectdb I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 184, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'NoneType' object is not callable
```

DB Config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'NAME': 'ProductionDB',
        'HOST': 'localhost,1433',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}
```

Also tried with HOST and PORT configured. Same result. Tried pyodbc as well and it says it doesn't support Django 1.11, which is what I'm using.